# How do you store and propagate state to nested ReactJS components?

Tags: reactjs

The scenario is this:

I have a form with dynamic (meaning they are not present on the initial render of the form) field sets.

So the main form would have fields for `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone`, etc and it would also have the possibility to add "rooms with items" like for example a bedroom with 2 chairs and a table.

I would like to store (to localStorage) and restore the state of the entire form (including it's dynamic components) but I'm having a hard time figuring out a way to easily do that.

I've tried storing everything in the main form's state but that becomes a nightmare to manage.

Is there anything that React provides for that purpose? Something that would allow me to take a snapshot and restore it later?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What do you use with React ? If you were using redux I would suggest using redux form http://erikras.github.io/redux-form/#/examples/dynamic?_k=5pwhl7 - you would be able to easily serialise/deserialise the form state to be persisted.

Comment: I'm using react with Ruby on Rails